# Make errors in R loud and noisy

Tags: r

R seems to take a very laissez-faire stance towards error handling, with behavior similar to most shell scripting languages. On top of that, R tends to print plenty of innocuous text to the terminal. This makes it easy for errors to go unnoticed. More than once I've had a script generate errors early on and then happily propagate NaNs through the rest of the calculation. Only after puzzling over the bizarre results for quite a while did I realize what had happened.

How do experienced R users deal with this? Is there a way to make errors fatal or at least more noticeable?

Comment: It is also the way how the langage is, and you have to adapt and learn to it. Mostly with a functional programming approach, split your code in small functions and always think about what would be a NA - Nan value as input/output and how you would manage it.
By the way can you elaborate this : `R tends to print plenty of innocuous text to the terminal`. I do not get it. And without minimal example reflecting what you find 'bad' in this langage it will be tricky to advise. Your question is too broad.

Comment: Conceptually, I'd prefer presumption to be that NaNs are errors so I don't have to always think about them. It seems unreasonable that I need to constantly fear for the integrity of my data in a statistics oriented language. As an example of innocuous text, successfully loading packages generates just enough output to obscure errors loading packages for me. Maybe that one should be more obvious to me but some days I'm tired and it isn't.

Comment: I do not see why loading successfully packages will obscure error. If an error happens, by definition your program stops in R that's it. Except if you handle it. But again, can you give a synthetic minimal example reflecting your thoughts?

Comment: Despite my attempt at a minimal answer, I think this question is promising, but vaguely worded. R has a very specific delineation of events into warnings and errors that you don't really get into. You might try editing your question to more precisely describe what sorts of behaviors you want to make more prominent.

Comment: Add a `stopifnot` after every step you deem important?

Comment: Your assumption that production of `NaN` is an error is 100% wrong.  It may be a **bug** , or you may have a situation where `NaN` is exactly the correct result.  Now, if you want to install the `seewave` package, and write `if(is.NaN(x)) play_a_sound_file` (I forget the name of the function), go right ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that one thing some people do is to run R with all warnings set to throw errors:

```
options(warn = 2)
> x <- "a"
> as.numeric(x)
Error: (converted from warning) NAs introduced by coercion
> sqrt(-1)
Error in sqrt(-1) : (converted from warning) NaNs produced
```

Obviously, this is in part a matter of taste. But you should be aware that adopting this approach will also include all warnings from packages, where the authors may or may not have a reasonable definition of what ought to generate a warning. So you might run into code that generates lots of warnings that you actually don't care about.

Then you'd have to turn to wrapping expressions in `suppressWarnings` to explicitly quiet the ones you decide don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I actually started programming with R before I learned any other languages. I quickly learned it was a bad idea to try and write a script and then run it just hoping it would work. Instead, I would follow this process:

1. Write down the input and output and end goal of a script I intended
   to write.
2. Try to achieve that using the command line interface step
   by step.
3. Gather all the lines needed to produce the desired result from the History tab in R Studio once I've succeeded with #2.

[image]

4. Test script and try to make optimizations.

This way you can **check to see each line is doing what you want it to, which in my opinion is important for its own sake.**

Too often I see questions here where people will do something like:

```
MyVec = c(2, 4, 3, 5)
for(i in MyVec)
{
    Sum = Sum + MyVec[i]
} 
Average = Sum / length(Sum)
```

**Note** this runs without error and produces the wrong result! If they would just take the time to run:

```
for(i in MyVec)
{
    print(i)
}
```

They would (a) see their mistake and (b) **learn a little about how R works!**

Comment: This is called test-driven development. Essentially. Or, as I like to call it, "bloody common sense"!

Comment: This is most definitely *not* what is normally called test-driven development. In particular, TDD advocates normally advise writing a test *before* writing any actual code. The cycle is not: write code, test code, but rather: write minimum test necessary to break existing code, *then* write minimum code necessary to pass test (repeat as needed).

Comment: I write to a script, doodle in the console if needed and run the script clean (or using knitr/markdown) to make sure it "compiles". A sort of a hybrid between what would normally be done in a compiled language and your way.